# How Should I Set Navigation Properties Before Inserting Into The Database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, .net-core, foreign-keys

*Note: I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71563553/how-to-get-modelstate-to-validate-data-submitted-through-a-view-model-with-forei/71565846#71565846) yesterday, but I've since moved past that problem into another issue. Although it's very closely related, I think it's best expressed in a separate question.*

I have three models: `Account`, `AccountType`, and `Person`. I want to make a single form page, through which a new Account, with a specific AccountType, and with specific Person information could be POSTed to the database.

```
public class AccountType
{
    [Key]
    public int AccountTypeID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string AccountTypeName { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    
    // Bunch of properties not relevant to the question here...
}

public class Account
{
    [Key]
    public int AccountID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AccountType")]
    public int AccountTypeID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Person")]
    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    // A few properties here...

    public virtual AccountType AccountType { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Since creating a new account requires me to insert into the account as well as the person table, I created a view model for both of these models:

```
public class Register
{
    public Account Account { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

In the Register view, I simply bound the properties from the Account and Person models to form fields. I also used a ViewBag to display a list of AccountTypes in a dropdown.

The part that I don't understand is in the POST controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Register(Register Register)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        _db.Accounts.Add(Register.Account);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return View(Register);
    }
    // do something else
}
```

The ModelState check passes successfully, after having commented out the Nullable setting in the project file. However, Register.Account has null properties:

[image: Register.Account has empty navigation properties]

All the values that I bound in the Register view get set correctly, but I did not bind the navigation properties (`Register.Account.AccountType` and `Register.Account.Person`) to anything, since I did not know what to do with them.

Now, I can't insert into the database with the above code, because I get a Person foreign key constraint error. It seems that `Register.Account` cannot have null values for its `Person` or `AccountType` navigation properties. Apparently, they must be set (or, at least, the `Person` property must be).

I know that I can set these navigation properties manually in the controller. For `Person`, I can write something like this before saving to the DB: `Register.Account.Person = Register.Person`, and I can likewise come up with something for `AccountTypes` to give it its proper value. I've tested this, and it does insert into the database.

But, this doesn't strike me as the right approach. It seems to me that there must be a better, more proper way of clarifying the model or table relationships to .NET before inserting into the database.

Does anybody know a better way?

P.S.: I'm using .NET 6.

Comment: Your view model shouldn't expose your data model as MVC will happily overbind to all properties.

Comment: I see. So, should my view model just serve as a repository for the properties that I want to capture (bind) from the form, so that in the POST action method I can create new instances of the models Account and Person, and then populate them with the data from the view model? Although I could probably figure it out, it would be useful to see a code example.

Comment: There are 3rd party tools which can help you with this. eg https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/automapper-in-c-sharp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Jeremy's suggestion, I solved this problem by creating a new View Model, which only included the properties that I needed to bind, and omitting any navigation properties that weren't necessary to insert into the database successfully.